# Implementing/Overriding MongoRepository Keep HATEOAS Formatting

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have a simple MongoRepository I would like to modify to return the generated ObjectId on post(save()).

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String>
{   
    public void delete(Employee employee);
    public Employee save(Employee employee);
    public Employee findOne(String id);
    public List<Employee> findAll();
    public Employee findByName(String principal);
}
```

I have explored ways to generate the id client side and pass it in the post BUT I really want Spring to handle this.

I've tried intercepting with a controller and returning the object in the ResponseBody, like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value=URI_EMPLOYEES, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    return repo.save(employee);
}
```

Problem with this is it forces me to re-work all the HATEOAS related logic Spring handles for me. Which is a MAJOR pain. (Unless I'm missing something.)

What's the most effective way of doing this without having to replace all of the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was using **@Controller** instead of **@RepositoryRestController** which was causing things to act up.

We can now easily override the POST method on this resource to return whatever we want while keeping spring-data-rest's implementation of the EmployeeRepository intact.

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class EmployeeController {

    private final static String URI_EMPLOYEES = "/employees";

    @Autowired private EmployeeRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(value=URI_EMPLOYEES, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<Employee> addVideo(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(repo.save(employee), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Changing from `@RestController` to `@RepositoryRestController` didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the interface:

```
public Employee save(Employee employee)
```

You can get the saved entity by simply doing

```
Employee saved = repository.save(employee);
return saved.getId();
```

The being said, you surely can generate the Id and set it via `setId()`. But once an ID is saved, it is immutable. Changing the Id and saving that entity would result in a new document saved in MongoDB.

Comment: I feel this is given. The problem is I can't simply override the functionality without losing the HATEOAS and HAL formatting Spring provides.

Comment: I guess I don't get it. You want HATEOAS, but for a given object. That should be easily done by letting the controller method return a HttpEntity<Employee> and creating an according ResponseEntity like in `return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(repo.save(employee), HttpStatus.OK);` Am I missing something here?

Comment: You're on point. My real concern was that when I implemented a Controller it would hide the Repository, forcring me to set re-implement everything. But it was because I was using (at)Controller instead of (at)RepositoryRestController. Now I can over JUST the post method, and leave the rest to Spring. Thanks and sorry for not being clear.