# Spring data rest - Is there a way to restrict the supported operations?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I want to expose data from a database as Restful APIs in a Spring(SpringBoot) application. Spring Data Rest appears to be an exact fit for purpose for this activity.

This database is read-only for my application needs. The default provides all the HTTP methods. Is there a configuration that I can use to restrict (in fact prevent) the other methods from being exposed?

Comment: The most convenient way would be to use Spring security to block everything other than GET requests. SDR does provide functionality in this area: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repository-crud-methods however handling at the HTTP level via Spring Security is simpler.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the Spring docs on [Hiding repository CRUD methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repository-crud-methods):

> 16.2.3. Hiding repository CRUD methods
>
> If you don’t want to expose a save or delete method on your
>   CrudRepository, you can use the @RestResource(exported = false)
>   setting by overriding the method you want to turn off and placing the
>   annotation on the overriden version. For example, to prevent HTTP
>   users from invoking the delete methods of CrudRepository, override all
>   of them and add the annotation to the overriden methods.
>
> ```
> @RepositoryRestResource(path = "people", rel = "people")
> interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
>
>   @Override
>   @RestResource(exported = false)
>   void delete(Long id);
>
>   @Override
>   @RestResource(exported = false)
>   void delete(Person entity);
> }
> ```
>
> It is important that you override both delete methods as the exporter
>   currently uses a somewhat naive algorithm for determing which CRUD
>   method to use in the interest of faster runtime performance. It’s not
>   currently possible to turn off the version of delete which takes an ID
>   but leave exported the version that takes an entity instance. For the
>   time being, you can either export the delete methods or not. If you
>   want turn them off, then just keep in mind you have to annotate both
>   versions with exported = false.

Comment: If you are reading this, you should think about up voting this ticket. SDR can be dangerous. 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1034

Comment: Is this still true with sping boot 2.0.2.RELEASE?

Comment: I am using JpaRepository. When I try to override  void delete(Long id);  I get an error message, "Method doe not override method from its super class" . What should I do in my case?

Comment: does not work for me...boot, data rest 1.5.4 RELEASE.

Comment: See @Snekse answer and use `RepositoryRestConfiguration.disableDefaultExposure()` and its documentation to export only explicitly marked repos/methods.

Comment: Also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59741296/8650621

Comment: don't forget to disable deleteAll() ;-)

Answer (score 12):

As of early 2018, there is now the [ability to only expose repository methods explicitly declared for exposure](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1176) (`DATAREST-1176`)

See [RepositoryRestConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/a10aa934b794bffb7bfbbac22e7bfc72ea4fdcc8/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.java)

A [Export false at Type level does not allow overriding with export true at Method level](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1034) ticket (`DATAREST-1034`) was opened, but closed as a duplicate of `DATAREST-1176`.  Oliver Gierke stated:

> I'll resolve this as fixed against the version of DATAREST-1176 for
>   now but feel free to reopen in case there's anything else you need.

They are not exact duplicates and the functionality described in `1034` would have been more user friendly, but there are at least some options now.

Comment: Could you please explain how this is possible? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @HamidMohayeji This may not entirely answer your question, but the `ExposureConfiguration` is probably the most correct way to configure this. 

*Customizing default exposure*
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.http-methods.default-exposure

* ExposureConfiguration* 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/mapping/ExposureConfiguration.html

Comment: @HamidMohayeji If the above comment fails, then getting a handle on the `RepositoryRestConfiguration` and setting the `repositoryDetectionStrategy` might be an option.  You can search that class for usage of `expose` as well as there are several options for changing default exposure.  There may be spring boot properties to adjust these things.

Comment: What if you want to to use JpaRepository, will it still work?

Comment: @nikiforos There's one way to find out 

Answer (score 3):

Since Spring Data REST 3.1, we can configure exposure per HTTP method. I used the following snippet to disable exposure of PUT, PATCH, POST and DELETE methods for items and collections:

```
@Component
public class SpringDataRestCustomization implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        ExposureConfiguration exposureConfiguration = config.getExposureConfiguration();
        exposureConfiguration.withItemExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.PUT)
                        .disable(HttpMethod.PATCH).disable(HttpMethod.POST).disable(HttpMethod.DELETE))
                .withCollectionExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.PUT)
                        .disable(HttpMethod.PATCH).disable(HttpMethod.POST).disable(HttpMethod.DELETE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring boot exposes all methods to REST. You can set that to false.

```
config.setExposeRepositoryMethodsByDefault(false);
```

For more information, you can refer org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.**RepositoryRestConfiguration**.

Sample code snippet to do this:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationRepositoryConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        ..........
        config.setExposeRepositoryMethodsByDefault(false);
    }
}
```