# How to disable specific REST method for @RepositoryRestResource in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I have a problem. Spring generates all REST methods for every repository annotated with @RepositoryRestResource annotation. The thing is, that for many resources I use in this project, we do not need all of the methods. It is slowing down the boot process of our application and generating redundant API links.

**My question is**: Is there a way to disable specific REST methods for specific repositories?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.setting-repository-detection-strategy), but there doesn't seem to be a way to disable within a single repo... How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516244/3641067) ? You have to explicitly override & put the annotation to disable I think.

Comment: You could try doing a custom repository implementation and overriding with `@RestResource(exported = false)` all the methods you want to disable. Then extend every repository you want to limit from your custom repository.